# Во время INSERT узнать id по которому будет добавлена строчка в mysql таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть обычная таблица в которую поступают данные от разных пользователей,
то есть каждый пользователь может добавить строчку в разное время.
Вопрос в том, можно ли узнать id, который будет присвоен позиции, до того, как данная строчка уже добавилась.
Способ который я знаю

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM `main`
```

Есть ли что то получше? Чтобы не попасть на момент когда процесс добавления позиции (другим пользователем) запустился, а данные в mysql еще не сохранились.

Comment: У меня как раз таки "правильная структура", то есть авто инкремент и т.д. на id UK PK AI...
нужен чтобы отправить как json ответ и далее использовать чтобы пользователь (на свое усмотрение) нажал checkbox и отправил на сервер еще один json. думаю что просто нужно усложнить `SELECT MAX(id) FROM main`

Comment: ok. буду пробовать. спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID не принято использовать до того, как он уже есть в базе. Поэтому лучше вставить и запись и получить ее ID сразу после вставки. Для этих целей в mysql специально предусмотрена функция `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. В php для этих целей существуют [функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php), которые надо вызвать сразу *после* того, как вставили новую запись:

```
mysql_insert_id($link);   - старый интерфейс mysql
mysqli_insert_id($link);  - mysqli
$link->lastInsertId();    - PDO
```

Если же вам все таки очень очень нужен id до того как вы вставите запись, то вам надо установить блокировку на таблицу с помощью `lock table`, получить `max(id)`, использовать его, сделать `insert` и только после этого сделать `unlock table`. Но этот подход явно более медленный и в общем нивелирует смысл auto_increment ID.