# Как получить id вставленной записи в mysql запросе?

Tags: php, mysql

Понимаю что нужно использовать функцию mysqli_insert_id, но не совсем понял как в процедурном стиле ее использовать, в моем случае:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO projects (project_name, ...
```

после чего мне нужно получить id вставленной записи с таблицы. Как это сделать?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Во время INSERT узнать id по которому будет добавлена строчка в mysql таблицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495913/%d0%92%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-insert-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-id-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-mysql-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83)

Comment: я и не понимаю. я читал документацию к функции, но на своем конкретном примере не понимаю как использовать. У меня подключение к бд идет далеко в хедере. дальше я просто пользуюсь функциями mysql_ . Что в качестве параметров надо передавать в функцию mysql-insert-id

Comment: Если вы во время выполнения insert явно передавали линк к базе (который не по умолчанию), то передавать его же. Если не передавали, так как пользуетесь подключением по умолчанию - то ничего не передавать

Comment: Я так и думал! спасибо. Значит я просто вызываю функцию без параметров, а она вернет id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно после вставления записи использовать `mysqli_insert_id` в таком синтаксе: `$lastInsertedId = mysqli_insert_id($dbConnect);` , где `$dbConnect` это переменная в которой хранится подключение к базе данных (результат `mysqli_connect`)

Comment: функции расширения mysqli не совместимы с расширением mysql, которое использует автор вопроса